# Texto sempre alinhado na Horizontal

Tags: css

Sei alinhar horizontalmente um texto. Sempre defino um `height` e um `line-height` e tudo fica certo. Porém no Chrome, o cursor, dentro de um `input` fica gigante, pois eu sempre defino tudo em `px`. Se eu colocar, por exemplo `line-height:auto` fica tudo certo, porém, fica bugado no IE, inclusive se eu usar `padding-top`.

Existe alguma forma que não ocorre esses contratempos?

Comment: experimenta utilizar o line-height:10px/9; saiba mais: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Comment: Cara. Excelente isso, não conhecia. Muito obrigado! Só que não resolve meu problema do Chrome

Comment: @ThallysonDias Posta isso como resposta.

Comment: Explica melhor seu problema, se possível coloca uma imagem de como esta ficando nos diferentes navegadores. @Renan isso não é uma resposta é só uma sugestão

Comment: Você usou os prefixos para cada navegador ? Como: -webkit-, -ms-, -o-, -moz- !

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar hack:

```
/* Hack firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {.selector {color:lime;}}

/* Hack Google Chrome */ 
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){.classe{width:246px;} } 

/* Hack Internet Explorer 6:*/  _background-color: blue;

/* Hack Internet Explorer 6 e 7:*/  *background-color: red;

/* Hack Internet Explorer 8:*/  background-color /*\**/: #FFCC00\9;

/* Hack Internet Explorer 9 e 10:*/  background-color: #FFCC00\9;
```